# Why CoreData is returning only 20 records?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I am using CoreData in my application. Everything is working fine except coredata is always returning max 20 records although i have more than 50 records. I have checked my code again and again but not finding the exact reason. I am also not using **fetchLimit** property. Kindly Help me.

Thanks.

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:entityName inManagedObjectContext:_manager.managedObjectContext];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = nil;
if (key != nil) {
    sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:key ascending:ascending];
    NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];
    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
}

NSError *error = nil;
NSMutableArray *array = [[_manager.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error] mutableCopy];
return array;
```

Comment: Are you checking results in NSLog?

Comment: Yeah.. It always returns 2o records.

Comment: There is no any default limit to fetch data from the core-data. I think something missing you are added. For bellowed the answer that setLimit only use if you want to set paging fetch only but based on OP there is no default limit.

Comment: How do you know that you have more than 50 records?

Comment: @TomHarrington Yes, I have more than 100 records.

Comment: But how do you know? Your question indicates that you can never find more than 20 entries. What *specifically* makes you certain that more than 20 exist?

Comment: @TomHarrington I have checked the .sqlite file generated by coredata and it has more that 20 records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSInteger rowCount = [context countForFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
fetchRequest.fetchLimit = rowCount;
NSArray *allItems = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
```

Here rowCount will calculate actual count of all rows and you can set it as `fetchLimit`

Comment: I have implemented the same but countForFetchRequest is always returning 20 after the 20 records added. Following are the results (separated by ,) when adding and fetching records.

1,2,3,........,17,18,19,20,20,20,20,.............

Answer (score -1):

Core Data returns 20 records by default. You can set records limit by using `setFetchLimit` of `NSFetchRequest` class.

```
NSFetchRequest* request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
[request setEntity:[...]];
[request setFetchLimit:50];
```

Comment: `autorelease` is not required in `ARC`, and now a days every project uses `ARC`, So no need of `autorelease`!

Comment: @user3305573 Thanks for the answer.. but I have 2 questions:-

1. I have checked some sample apps and they also are not using fetchLimit, but they are working fine.. How?

2. If I set the ftechlimit to 50, it'll return max 50 records. Is there any way so that I can get all records regardless of limit and need not to set any limit.

Comment: @HimanshuGarg This will work only when when rows are less than or equal to 50. If its more than 50 (Lets say 70), above code will not work. You have to actual calculate count of rows.

Comment: *"Core Data returns 20 records by default"*. That is not true.